# How to read file in MIPS

Tags: file, assembly, mips, file-read

I have the following file, and I'd like to be able to read the file into 2 buffers in MIPS, but only after an offset of 4 chars and I'm just wondering how I'd do that, I tried having two reads where I store `abc d` in buffer1 and another read call where I store `"def ghi jkl mno"` but that didn't work

```
abc def ghi jkl mno
```

Here's the code, if someone can tell me how to correctly manipulate the pointer to the contents of the file, that would be appreciated

```
# Open (for reading) a file
  li $v0, 13       # system call for open file
  la $a0, filename    # output file name
  li $a1, 0        # flags
  syscall          # open a file (file descriptor returned in $v0)

  move $t0, $v0    # save file descriptor in $t0        
  
  # Read to file just opened  
  li $v0, 14       # system call for read to file
  la $a1, buffer1   # address of buffer from which to write
  li $a2, 4       # hardcoded buffer length
  move $a0, $t0    # put the file descriptor in $a0     
  syscall          # write to file

  li $v0, 14       # system call for read to file
  la $a1, buffer   # address of buffer from which to write
  li $a2, 15       # hardcoded buffer length
  move $a0, $t0    # put the file descriptor in $a0     
  syscall
```

Comment: Define _"didn't work"_. Anyway, there's no need for an extra buffer. You could just let the second read overwrite data read by the first one.

Comment: File offset of 4, like a seek or read + discard?  IDK if MARS toy system calls have an `lseek` (no mention of it in https://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html), so you might need to read 4 bytes, then read again with the same pointer.  Or do you mean read the whole file into memory starting with the 4th byte of a buffer in memory?